# Creating a round button with the same for the same one and two chars?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a button which has the same dimensions and looks exactly the same like all the other buttons. But one button will contain only one char like `M` and some will contain `XL` or `XS`. My question now is, how I can make them look the same?

In the picture below you can see three buttons. The two buttons right have the same CSS settings. But one button is bigger then the other one because the middle button contains only one char and the right one two chars...

If I now adjust the CSS settings for the middle button to let it look round again, the button is getting smaller... So, my question now is, how can I create buttons who have the same dimensions all the time, netherless if they contain one or two chars?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc2BU.png)

Kind regards

Comment: Could you please add the HTML and CSS you're using now.

Comment: Add some `width` and `height` (same values) and add `border-radius`. Make content center aligned using flex or table properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
span {
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #26AEF2;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<span>S</span>
<span>XS</span>
<span>XL</span>
<span>XXL</span>
<span>XXXL</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but I'm gonna try:

- put every single `<button>` in a separate `<div>` or `<span>`
- style the `<div>` or `<span>` with a fixed width and height

Comment: Fixed it @slacker